# Como carregar arquivos .txt de um diretório incluindo na lista ou dataframe o nome deste arquivo em Python?

Tags: python, lista, pandas, txt, dataframe

estou no Jupyter Notebook trabalhando com Python.
Tenho um diretório com arquivos em txt, consigo iterar no diretório e carregar estes arquivos em txt, porém, preciso pegar também o nome deste arquivo como coluna da lista ou dataframe.

Segue figura do diretório.
[image: diretório com arquivos]

Segue o código atual e o resultado deste.

```
allLines = []
path = 'C:/data/txt/'
fileList = os.listdir(path)
for i in fileList:
    file = open(os.path.join('C:/data/txt/'+ i), 'r', encoding='UTF-8')
    allLines.append(file.read())
print(allLines)
```

Depois com o resultado carrego para um dataframe.

```
#Codigo
raw_data = pd.DataFrame(data=allLines, columns=['texto'])
```

[image: Resultado esperado]

Como resultado final desejo obter o conteúdo e também o nome do arquivo, é possível? Pode ajudar?
Grato.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se entendi bem, seria este o resultado que deseja?

```
allLines = []
path = 'C:/data/txt/'
fileList = os.listdir(path)
for i in fileList:
    file = open(os.path.join('C:/data/txt/'+ i), 'r', encoding='UTF-8')
    allLines.append(file.read())

dados = {
"conteudo": allLines,
"arquivo": fileList
}
raw_data = pd.DataFrame(dados)
```

Comment: Opi, obrigado camarada, consegui com isso o nome dos arquivos, porém, nesse dataframe eu preciso do nome dos arquivos e seus respectivos textos, tem como?

Comment: Seria um dataframe para cada arquivo ou um único dataframe com todos os arquivos e seus repectivos nomes no meio dos conteúdos?

Comment: um único dataframe com todos os dados e com duas colunas, coluna com nome do arquivo e outra coluna com o respectivo texto do arquivo

Comment: Editei a resposta, veja se é da maneira que deseja

Comment: Exatamente, testarei outros lances aqui, muito obrigado camarada e bom dia.